# c++ for loops(c++11 way and older versions way)

Tags: c++, c++11

I just started begin to learn c++.
I was taught how to write a simple for loop

e.g

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

but often see people using the word **auto** in their **for loops** nowadays.

Assuming I have a vector with some data and these data will be brought over to a map

e.g

in c++11 way

```
vector<char> vec;
map<char, int> myMap;
vec.push_back('a');
vec.push_back('b');
vec.push_back('b');
vec.push_back('c');

// Loop through the vector
for (auto x : vec) {
   ++myMap[x]; 
}

for (auto x : myMap) {

}
```

is this equivalent to

```
vector<char> vec;
map<char, int> myMap;
vec.push_back('a');
vec.push_back('b');
vec.push_back('b');
vec.push_back('c');

for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
    ++myMap[v[x]];
}

for (int x = 0; x < myMap.size() x++) {
   //print content in map
}
```

Comment: Neither code fragment would compile - this, at least, they have in common.

Comment: I also don't believe it is possible to dereference an auto type that is pointing to character types. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In the first one you're trying to index into a `map<char, int>` using a `string` (that has been dereferenced, no less, but let's ignore that part). In the second you're trying to dereference a `char`.

Comment: my apologies to all. I tried my best to come up with an example. pardon me if my example given is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent in effect, not in terms of efficiency. Here's the exact translation as defined by the standard:

```
for (auto element : container) {
  //Stuff
}
```

is translated to this iterator-based loop:

```
auto&& __range = container; 
for (auto __itr = std::begin(container),  __end = std::end(container);
     __itr != __end; ++__itr) { 
   element = *__itr;
   //Stuff
}
```

In particular, this is different in that it only evaluates the end once (as opposed to calling `v.size()` many times) and it uses iterators instead of indices. It also provides a cleaner interface in that:

1. You know it *must* loop over all elements (unless you use break/continue).
2. You know it *must* loop one element at a time (unless you use break/continue).
3. It hides the use of indices/iterators with syntactic sugar :).

Few other things:

1) `auto` is a separate language feature. You need not use `auto` to use a range-based for loop, for example:

```
for (int i : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) {
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Is a perfectly legal way to print the numbers 1-5.

2) Instead of using push_back to fill your example vectors, prefer to use 'universal initialization`:

```
vector<char> vec { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
```

3) When using the range-based for loop with non-primitive types, prefer to use `auto&` or `const auto&` as your range-declaration type. For example

```
vector<string> v { "Hello", "world" };
for (const auto& elt : v) {
  cout << elt << endl;
}
```

We do this because copying things other than primitives is usually expensive, and by default, a copy would happen. Here we take an alias, saving us a string copy, and therefore the performance cost of an allocation.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Technicality: The translation I gave is slightly inaccurate because it does not handle all cases in the same exact way that the standard would (it prefers member function begin/end and arrays get special treatment). I simplified it for ease of understanding. See my source above for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dereference an `int` variable.  Your old style example needs to be updated slightly:

```
for (int x= 0 ; ( x < v.size() ) ; x ++ ) {
  ++ myMap[ v[x] ] ;
}
```

But no one really did it that way in old style C++, they used iterators:

```
for ( vector<int>::iterator itptr= v.begin() ; ( itptr != v.end() ) ; ++ itptr ) {
  ++ myMap[ * itptr ] ;
}
```

This form of the for loop gets easier in C++11 because of `auto`:

```
for ( auto itptr= v.begin() ; ( itptr != v.end() ) ; ++ itptr ) {
  ++ myMap[ * itptr ] ;
}
```

But as you have seen, the new `for` form is the simplest:

```
// Loop through the vector
for (auto x : vec) {
 ++myMap[x]; 
}
```

but notice I didn't dereference `x`, `x` is the character.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the new auto type, as well as saying not to dereference x since it points to a character.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, they are equivalent.

Except in both cases, you should *not* have attempted to deference `x` because, in both cases, this is a syntax error.

Comment: @user3175729: I have updated my answer to suit the edit to your question.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. This loop for(int i = 0; i<vector.size(); i++) {
    //do stuff
} is invalid. The correct loop for ( std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++ ) where T is some type.

Comment: I do not think so because I already several times encountered that the reason of aborting of a program was the using int in such loops. Now many platforms are 64-bit.

Comment: @Vlad: No, `int` here will not abort anything; your previous comment runs the risk of aborting your SO reputation (such as it is).

Comment: Here you can get an infinite loop. If it is better for you then I am gald. I think you know what reputation you have from me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you're mistaking his code with yours.

Comment: Then reread the thread and your post again. I think that three times will be enough.

Comment: @Vlad: Okay I'll let you know when I have read it sufficient times. Thanks for your advice.